# QtCreator error with undeclared identifier 'Q_NULLPTR'

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

This is an example of an error that I had when I tried to compile a very simple code.

The code works in Windows, but not in my Mac.

> ../../../../Qt5.8.0/5.8/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.h:103:65:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'Q_NULLPTR'
>
> ../../../../Qt5.8.0/5.8/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.h:135:63:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'Q_RELOCATABLE_TYPE';

and there are more of errors like this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimum Compilable Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could use to help you. Basically it's hard to give an answer that is not based on guesswork to some extent until you show us your code and (possibly) your project files.

Comment: What file of code I should provide ? .pro or the somewhat relevant code ?

Comment: the rule of thumb is to make the smallest possible example that still has this problem, and post it here. I suppose in your case a `.cpp` and a `.pro` file would be needed

Comment: I've just used the code that works on other computers, but not on my Mac.